# How should I set up connection to PAServer from a MacBook Pro?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, parallels, paserver

I have previously done iOS development from my work PC, and connected to PAServer on the mac through a hardwired network connection. Now, I have Parallels installed on the Mac and would like to work from anywhere, all contained within this MacBook Pro.

PAServer however works via IP Address. The Mac is subject to switch across different WiFi networks, as well as between WiFi and a hardwire - or possibly without any network at all. I would hate to have to keep reconfiguring my connection to PAServer every time my IP Address changes.

How should I set up my development environment in Parallels so that it persists a permanent connection to a never-changing IP on PAServer?

Answer (score 2):

VM's have an external IP that connects to your internet stack. You set up PAServer to connect to that IP addy. I used to use Parallels when XE2-3 was out, and I had no trouble configuring PAServer, but I don't recall details now. I switched to VMWare Fusion because I got tired of paying for an upgrade every year when OS X was upgraded.

Try opening a command shell and typing ifconfig.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what David Schwartz was saying, the parallels internal IP connection is nothing to do with the one that OS X uses in airports etc., and does not change from session to session. For me it was on an entirely different sub-mask (the ip address was not the usual 192...). Set up PAServer and run it on the mac. Select the i command and you will probably see in addition to the usual 192.x.x.x locations one (or more) starting 10.x.x.x These will be the internal IP addresses that you can use to link to parallels and will not change.